# How to check if cellular data is enabled

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to check if cellular data is enabled on my Android app. I found this code but it has deprecated code. I can't find a way to do it without using deprecated code.

```
private bool IsCellularDataEnabled(Context context)
{
    var cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);

    if (cm == null) return false;

    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.M)
    {
        var ni = cm.ActiveNetworkInfo;

        if (ni == null) return false;
        
        return ni.IsConnected && ni.Type == ConnectivityType.Mobile;
    }

    return cm.GetNetworkCapabilities(cm.ActiveNetwork).HasTransport(Android.Net.TransportType.Cellular);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=android) for this? It features different [connection profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.connectionprofile?view=xamarin-essentials-android) to check against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing an SDK check before running the deprecated code. This means you will never run any deprecated code on any device ever. So there is no problem.

Your code can be improved by catching a `NoSuchMethodError` instead of an SDK check. This is better because there is no risk you are checking for a wrong SDK version.

I have written the improved code in Java (I hope you don't mind). But as already said you can also stick to your code.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private boolean IsCellularDataEnabled(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm == null) return false;

    try {
        return cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.getActiveNetwork()).hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
        android.net.NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) return false;
        return ni.isConnected() && ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is clearly asking for a Xamarin implementation, which uses C#.

Comment: @Julian Then you didn't read my answer properly. In the first paragraph I am saying that everything is fine with his code.

Comment: Then you should've written a comment instead, IMHO.

Comment: You can ask ChatGPT to translate this to C#

Answer (score 0):

Using [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=android), you could do the following and check against the required [connection profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.connectionprofile?view=xamarin-essentials-android):

```cs
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class YourClass
    {
        private bool IsCellularDataEnabled()
        {
            var profiles = Connectivity.ConnectionProfiles;
            return profiles.Contains(ConnectionProfile.Cellular);
        }
    }
}
```

This checks if mobile data are enabled on the device.

Don't forget to enable the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission, e.g. by adding this line to the *AndroidManifest.xml* (if you haven't already done so):

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```